# SSH Network error: Connection refused

Tags: networking, ubuntu, ssh, sftp

I was trying to setup sublime text editor to connect via sftp on my server but was getting connection timeout all the time. 
I found a solution and followed this article :
https://superuser.com/a/957666

They suggested to change the server config to accept a mac algorithm used by the client by adding this `hmac-sha1` on `KexAlgorithms`. 
So in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`, I changed:

```
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1
```

to

```
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,hmac-sha1
```

And now i try to login on my server and i get `Network error: Connection refused`

How can i regain access to my server? My server is hosted on kimsufy.

Comment: if you're trying to troubleshoot ssh why not do it normally i.e. not with sublime.. then add sublime if you have it working normally.  And can you show a screenshot of sftp in sublime, it sounds interesting.

Answer (score 0):

`Network error: Connection refused` means that the server refused to open the connection (at the TCP level). The usual cause is that sshd is not running.

I think sshd does not like something in the configuration and aborts. Look in the sshd log.

By the way `hmac-sha1` does not seems to be a valid value for `KexAlgorithms` but for `MACs`